# How to avoid hanging Xvfb processes [while using PyVirtualDisplay]?

Tags: python, process, subprocess, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

Trying to find how to avoid hanging Xvfb processes in our Python application, when using PyVirtualDisplay.  The essential problem is that calling `display.stop()` (see code sample below) does not seem to properly shut down the Xvfb process.

PyVirtualDisplay is very simply used:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(backend='xvfb')
display.start()

... # Some stuff happens here

display.stop()
```

Now, the Display class has a slight modification to prevent Xvfb from using TCP ports: basically, add `-nolisten tcp` to the executing command.  The modification is done by overriding the appropriate XfvbDisplay class's _cmd property:

```
@property
def _cmd(self):
    cmd = [PROGRAM,
           dict(black='-br', white='-wr')[self.bgcolor],
           '-screen',
           str(self.screen),
           'x'.join(map(str, list(self.size) + [self.color_depth])),
           self.new_display_var,
           '-nolisten',
           'tcp'
           ]
    return cmd
```

What is the proper way to end the Xvfb processes in this context so that they are terminated and do not linger?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Assuming pyvirtualdisplay uses `subprocess.Popen`, you could call terminate on those objects. If you can't get access to those, then you could try using [os.kill](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill) on all child processes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your display, since it inherits from EasyProcess, will have a popen attribute at `display.popen`. You can use this to terminate, if EasyProcess isn't working properly.

So, you can do something like this:

```
display.popen.terminate()
```

or

```
display.popen.kill()
```

Comment: Thanks.  What happens if I don't have access to the display object anymore?  Is there a nicer way of doing a `kill` than using an OS call?

Comment: That's what it's doing behind the scenes too, actually. The answer is no, not really. os.kill is pretty good actually. It's a decent interface and you can handle exceptions easily enough.

Answer (score 8):

[The answer by Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476510/how-to-avoid-hanging-xvfb-processes-while-using-pyvirtualdisplay/18831724#18831724) did not work for me. This worked:

```
display.sendstop()
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, none of these solutions work for me. It says display doesn't have an attribute sendstop or popen.